# Dúvida no código de PA no Python

Tags: python

> Estava com Dúvida em uma resolução de exercício em Python.

```py
       pri_termo = int(input('Digite o primeiro Termo: '))
       razao = int(input('Digite a Razão da PA: '))
       termo = pri_termo
       cont = 1
    while cont <= 10:
       print('{} --> '.format(termo), end='')
       termo += razao
       cont += 1
```

A minha real dúvida é pq fazer o 'termo' corresponder ao 'pri_termo', sendo q os dois teriam o mesmo valor?
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Bom, essa é uma questão muito específica e creio que esteja fora do escopo do site. Mas note que isso ocorreu apenas pq o nome utilizado dentro do loop é `termo`. Seria possível utilizar apenas o nome `pri_termo`, mas para isso seria preciso alterar o nome da variável dentro do loop

Comment: Tem sentido se, por qualquer motivo, você quiser preservar o valor de `pri_termo`. Se não houver tal necessidade então você pode utilizar apenas uma variável.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa criar a variavel termo. Segue o código um pouco mudado:

```
pri_termo = int(input('Digite o primeiro Termo: '))
razao = int(input('Digite a Razão da PA: '))
cont = 1
while cont <= 10:
    if cont < 10:
        print('{} --> '.format(pri_termo), end='')
    elif cont == 10:
        print('{}'.format(pri_termo), end='')
    pri_termo += razao
    cont += 1
```

Comment: Agora se vc quiser presevar de alguma forma o valor da variavel pri_termo, faz sentido criar outra variavel, mas para o caso de uma PA, acho que não faz muito sentido a criação.

Answer (score 0):

Para que o código funcione não é necessário criar e atribuir a um nova variável chamada `termo` o valor de `pri_termo`, mas ele fez isso para que o valor do primeiro termo não fosse alterado.

Veja bem, se em algum outro lugar do seu código você precisasse obter o valor do primeiro termo, como você faria isso já que a variável `pri_termo` seria somada com `razao` ? Seria muito melhor então, preservar `pri_termo` e criar uma outra variável para ser alterada.

Se quiser, dá até para fazer várias melhorias nesse código de resolução. No exemplo abaixo, o código funciona sem precisar de uma nova variável e sem alterar o valor de `pri_termo`:

```
pri_termo = int(input('Digite o primeiro Termo: '))
razao = int(input('Digite a Razão da PA: '))
limit = 10

for n in range(limit):
    print('{} --> '.format(pri_termo + (n * razao)), end = '')
```